# Android Studio project detected

Tags: java, android, node.js, xml, cordova

I am beginner programmer. I need some help as I am trying to convert HTML 5 website to Android app & IOS App,

But i have the following issue:

```
D:\andriod\anditest1>cordova build android --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Android Studio project detected
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms\android\platform_www] to platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www
Wrote out android application name "THMLhybrid" to D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "com.cmsfreindly.com" to D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\cmsfreindly\com\MainActivity.java
This app does not have launcher icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
(node:2340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
    at D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:305:19
    at _fulfilled (D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\andriod\anditest1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
(node:2340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2340) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

D:\andriod\anditest1>
```

is there anything missing tools needed to be downloaded other than java oracle?

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download Android Studio and make sure the path is in the environment variable ANDROID_HOME.  You will also need Java SE Development Kit 8u162 as well.

Android Studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Java
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

English:
i had the same problem. you can run `$ cordova requirements` into your folder project to see dependences and solve them

Español:
Yo tenía el mismo problema. lo solucioné ejecutando el comando `$ cordova requirements` dentro del directorio del proyecto, ahí me dí cuenta de que debía instalar y corregir.

Answer (score 0):

Please note I am not a programmer . I am ex Banker and entrepreneur now .I got really frustrated while setting cordova with all those errors  for building android apps in windows. Though, I now understand this is the simplest cake, if you know the know-how. I love coding, so I am sharing the whole length of steps .  You can figure out what step you are missing.

**Step 1. Requirements :**

- (a)node js ( npm )-- install it
- (b) Install cordova by command -->
   npm install -g cordova
- (c) Install Phone gap by command --> npm
    install -g phonegap
- (d) Ant apache ( download bin  not source ) by visiting

https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi . Keep this in C:/ Program files

- (e) JDK version 8 . you can down load previous version by visiting
  oracle.com

---

**NOTE : Keep ( ANT ) and JDK in Same Folder i.e extracted (d) and (e) in C:/Program files**

---

**Step: 2 Setting Environment Variables**
you can visit : Control Panel\System and Security\System--> environment variables You can see two types of windows : User and System

User Environment Variables:
You have to set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME

Add new variable :
Variable name :ANT_ HOME
Variable value : C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3

Variable name :JAVA_ HOME
Variable value :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

System Environment Variables: edit path and at the end use ; and paste ant/bin address
PATH :
Variable name :path
Variable value :....C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3\bin

---

**NOTE : Check ant & java configuration by windows command prompt :
ant -version and java --version . If using git then git --version.
If you error free then proceed further.**

---

**Step 3. Create a cordova project**
something like this command: cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

**Step 4. create platform android or ios: ensure proper config.xml**

**Step 5. now check cordova requirements: This work in app folder only **

Now build your app.

**Other errors you get if you miss these:**

- check  ="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" in config xml.
- Add Required Plugin - cordova plugin add -- as you need in config.xml
- Cordova requirements: This work in app folder only
- Cant find the Ant Version: you have not used ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME folder name.Ensure ANT_Home and JAVA_HOME only in User folder while the path in System Variable. Never use / " or ' in writing these variables.

"IF YOU DONT REQUIRE ANT AND GIT ---> Dont download it "

Hope this helps beginners and code layman like me.