# Cordova Project from Github

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, github

I m cloning a cordova app sourcecode from github. How do I install cordova and add android platform to it and build it in Android Studio?
After cloning the code, I am installing cordova, but cant add platform or anything related to cordova. Is there any tutorial on how to follow the correct steps to make it run in Android Studio?  I am very new to Cordova. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: follow the GitHub repo's README and look for installation instructions.

To play around with a cordova app, you most definitely need the cordova CLI. If you haven't already, install NodeJS and npm from http://nodejs.org or using your package manager of choice. Then inside a terminal run

```
npm install -g cordova
```

(If you are using Linux you probably have to run that command with `sudo`)

Now you navigate into the cloned github repo and run

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

It will create a directory under `./platforms/android` which you can open using Android Studio. Then you can run the app with an emulator or a connected device.

If at any point you receive error messages or you think something is missing, you can run (inside the GitHub cloned repo)

```
cordova requirements
```

It will show you if the cordova CLI is missing something. You will have to fix all the errors that come up. Consult the cordova documentation under https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#installing-the-cordova-cli in order to do that.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks! Will try like how you had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please note I am not a programmer . I am ex Banker and entrepreneur now .I got really frustrated while setting cordova with all those errors  for building android apps in windows. Though, I now understand this is the simplest cake, if you know the know-how. I love coding, so I am sharing the whole length of steps .  You can figure out what step you are missing.

**Step 1. Requirements :**

- (a)node js ( npm )-- install it
- (b) Install cordova by command -->
   npm install -g cordova
- (c) Install Phone gap by command --> npm
    install -g phonegap
- (d) Ant apache ( download bin  not source ) by visiting

https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi . Keep this in C:/ Program files

- (e) JDK version 8 . you can down load previous version by visiting
  oracle.com

---

**NOTE : Keep ( ANT ) and JDK in Same Folder i.e extracted (d) and (e) in C:/Program files**

---

**Step: 2 Setting Environment Variables**
you can visit : Control Panel\System and Security\System--> environment variables You can see two types of windows : User and System

User Environment Variables:
You have to set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME

Add new variable :
Variable name :ANT_ HOME
Variable value : C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3

Variable name :JAVA_ HOME
Variable value :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

System Environment Variables: edit path and at the end use ; and paste ant/bin address
PATH :
Variable name :path
Variable value :....C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3\bin

---

**NOTE : Check ant & java configuration by windows command prompt :
ant -version and java --version . If using git then git --version.
If you error free then proceed further.**

---

**Step 3. Create a cordova project**
something like this command: cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

**Step 4. create platform android or ios: ensure proper config.xml**

**Step 5. now check cordova requirements: This work in app folder only **

Now build your app.

**Other errors you get if you miss these:**

- check  ="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" in config xml.
- Add Required Plugin - cordova plugin add -- as you need in config.xml
- Cordova requirements: This work in app folder only
- Cant find the Ant Version: you have not used ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME folder name.Ensure ANT_Home and JAVA_HOME only in User folder while the path in System Variable. Never use / " or ' in writing these variables.

"IF YOU DONT REQUIRE ANT AND GIT ---> Dont download it "

Hope this helps beginners and code layman like me.
Answered on: [Android Studio project detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488620/android-studio-project-detected/49948846#49948846)